# wget does not fetch file from link

Tags: wget

I am typing the command

```
wget http://bookfi.org/dl/1029034/ad9e54
```

in bash and I don't get the file, instead i get an html page.

If I give the same link to freedownloadmanager, it does fetch the file.

Why is this behaviour?

Can curl fetch me the file?

Comment: What file is it supposed to get? in Firefox the link is redirecting me to some other Russian md5sum page.

Comment: http://en.bookfi.org/book/1029034

Answer (score 2):

The link you're using (`http://bookfi.org/dl/1029034/ad9e54`) isn't a direct link to the file. When I opened it in Firefox, it redirected me to the much longer `http://dl.lux.bookfi.org/genesis/408000/7def946a9159159e60931e25e71f23eb/_as/%5BCommittee_on_Advanced_Engineering_Environments,_N(BookFi.org).pdf`, which is what you have to feed into the wget command.

The reason it worked for `freedownloadmanager` was probably because it has a facility which lets it follow redirects. I don't know about curl; it'll depend on whether *it* follows redirects or not.

Comment: Then, is it possible to make a script that redirects?

Comment: According to the wget man page,there is a `--referer=*url*` option, where `*url*` is the page you got the download link from. This is to be used for dynamic websites which expect people to be using web-browsers and don't work properly unless they know which page you came from. It seems to work for the link you gave in the question: `wget "http://bookfi.org/dl/1029034/ad9e54" --referer="http://en.bookfi.org/book/1029034"`